# What causes SSH host identification to change / How is it calculated?

Tags: linux, ssh

I know that the ssh host identification is supposed to protect you from man-in-the-middle-attacks, but I could not figure out what exactly goes into the calculation of the checksum.

What exactly has to change to in order to get the "REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED" alert?

Comment: I once had the [server's SSH key re-generated because some SSH component had been updated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472331/can-a-server-ssh-key-change-due-to-software-upgrades) (link has several ways to check that this happened).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSH host's public key offered by the server. Specifically this is stored in `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` (or `ssh_host_dsa_key`, or possibly another key type, they are all named similarly.)

What SSH is trying to tell you here is that the fingerprint of that public key it stored when it first connected to the server (in your `.ssh/known_hosts` file) isn't what it's getting when it connects to a server with the same name.

If you don't understand why that happened, it could be that someone has hijacked your DNS, connecting you to a server that you were not expecting, or that the keys were unexpectedly changed.

As to how to regenerate these, [the commands are covered in this cloudvps article](https://www.cloudvps.com/knowledgebase/entry/2481-regenerating-ssh-host-keys/).

Comment: https://www.cloudvps.com/knowledgebase/entry/2481-regenerating-ssh-host-keys/ not working